# Android what should be the height & width of button, spinner, radiobuttons, checkboxs so that it well fitted on screen

Tags: android, spinner, selecteditem

How to set spinner with text and key value like html option select
If it cant be done which is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Here is another StackOverflow question with a possible solution for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424841/whats-the-correct-way-to-implement-key-value-pair-in-spinner-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an adapter.  Look [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html).